# Real world practice to store secrets and config in Lua scripts for nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I have some Lua scripts embedded in nginx. In one of those scripts I connect to my Redis cache and do it like so:

```
local redis_host = "127.0.0.1"
local redis_port = 6379
...
local ok, err = red:connect(redis_host, redis_port);
```

I do not like this, because, I have to hard code host and port. Should I instead use something like .ini file, parse it in Lua and get configuration information from this file? How do they solve this problem in real world practice?

Besides, I my scripts I use RSA decryption and encryption. For example, I do it like so now:

```
   local public_key = [[ -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAL7udJ++o3T6lgbFwWfaD/9xUMEZMtbm GvbI35gEgzjrRcZs4X3Sikm7QboxMJMrfzjQxISPLtsy9+vhbITQNVkCAwEAAQ== -----END PUBLIC KEY----- ]]
   ...
   local jwt_obj = jwt:verify(public_key, token)
```

Once again what I do not like about this, is that I have to hard code public key. Do they use it in production like so or use some other techniques to store secrets (like storing them in environment variable)?

Comment: This is way too broad for a short SO answer. Key management and server provisioning are topics that books are written about, not snippets.

Comment: Does it mean, that in real practice they do not hard code secrets and configs in Lua scripts?

Comment: Real practice has seen unspeakable things. Doesn't mean they should be done.

Comment: I don't think, that there is an infinite amount of ways to use secrets and configuration data in Lua scripts. 1) hard code (sounds like a bad practice) 2) store in separate files (sounds good, because you separate concerns, but may be bad because you increase I/O operations) 3) store in environment variables (sounds even better, because you again separate concerns and probably it does not require so much of I/O operations).

Comment: Lua lets you use Lua scripts as config files.  Just place this in separate file "secret.lua": `return { public_key = "...here is the public key...", redis_host = "127.0.0.1", redis_port = 6379}` and invoke it from your main program as `local secret = require("secret"); print(secret.redis_host)`

Comment: Thank you, Egor! This idea did not cross my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure *some* people do it this way in production. It is all a matter of what you're comfortable with and what your standards are. Some things that should determine your approach here -

1. What is the sensitivity of the data and risk if it were to be available publicly?
2. What is your deployment process? If you use an infrastructure as code approach or some type of config management then you surely don't want these items sitting embedded within code.

To solve the first item around sensitivity of the data, you'd need to consider many different scenarios of the best way to secure the secrets. Standard secret stores like AWS Parameter Store and CredStash are built just for this purpose and you'd need to pull the secrets at runtime to load them to memory. 
 For the second item, you could use a config file that is replaced per deployment.

To get the best of both worlds, you'd need to combine both a secure mechanism for storing secrets and a configuration approach for deployments/updates.

Like was mentioned in the comments, there are books written on both of these topics so the chances of getting enough detail in a SO answer is unlikely.